# php JOIN statement only returns one row from second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this statement in php:

```
$takeBL = $connection -> prepare("SELECT bestelldatabase.*, zurückschreibendatas.* FROM bestelldatabase LEFT JOIN zurückschreibendatas USING (lieferscheinid) WHERE bestelldatabase.lieferscheinid = ?");
$takeBL -> execute([$_GET['id']]);
while ($getAllBL = $takeBL -> fetch()) {

    array_push($products, $getAllBL);
}
```

This all works, but the only problem is, that sql only returns the first matched row from the joined table an pushes them into the array. 
I dont understand much of join statement and I get really confused when I try to google for answers.

These are all rows with from "bestelldatabase" with the "lieferscheinid" 37:
[image: bestelldatabase rows]

And here you can see all rows from "zurückschreibendatas" with "lieferscheinid" 37:
[image: zurückschreibendatas rows]

And also for better understanding, this is >var_dump($products):

```
array(22) { 
["id"]=> string(3) "150" [0]=> string(3) "143" 
["lieferscheinid"]=> string(2) "37" [1]=> string(2) "37" 
["warenid"]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "2" 
["anzahl"]=> string(2) "12" [3]=> string(2) "12" 
["flaschen"]=> string(1) "0" [4]=> string(1) "0" 
[5]=> string(3) "150" 
[6]=> string(2) "37" 
["bestellid"]=> string(3) "140" [7]=> string(3) "140" 
["gesamtkisten"]=> string(2) "15" [8]=> string(2) "15" 
["gesamtflaschen"]=> string(1) "0" [9]=> string(1) "0" 
["zurückkisten"]=> string(1) "6" [10]=> string(1) "6" 
["zurückflaschen"]=> string(1) "0" [11]=> string(1) "0" 
}
```

And for even better understanding, there is another row va dumped:

```
array(22) { 
["id"]=> string(3) "150" [0]=> string(3) "142" 
["lieferscheinid"]=> string(2) "37" [1]=> string(2) "37" 
["warenid"]=> string(1) "7" [2]=> string(1) "7" 
["anzahl"]=> string(1) "6" [3]=> string(1) "6" 
["flaschen"]=> string(1) "0" [4]=> string(1) "0" 
[5]=> string(3) "150" 
[6]=> string(2) "37" 
["bestellid"]=> string(3) "140" [7]=> string(3) "140" 
["gesamtkisten"]=> string(2) "15" [8]=> string(2) "15" 
["gesamtflaschen"]=> string(1) "0" [9]=> string(1) "0" 
["zurückkisten"]=> string(1) "6" [10]=> string(1) "6" 
["zurückflaschen"]=> string(1) "0" [11]=> string(1) "0" 
}
```

EDIT 
This is my edited statement:

```
"SELECT 
b.id, 
b.lieferscheinid, 
b.warenid, 
b.anzahl, 
b.flaschen, 
z.id, 
z.lieferscheinid, 
z.bestellid, 
z.gesamtkisten, 
z.gesamtflaschen, 
z.zurückkisten, 
z.zurückflaschen 
FROM bestelldatabase AS b 
LEFT JOIN zurückschreibendatas AS z 
USING (lieferscheinid) 
WHERE b.lieferscheinid = ?"
```

And I also forgot to mention one important thing: If I change the WHERE clause from "WHERE b.lieferscheinid = ?" to "WHERE z.lieferscheinid = ?"

the issue turns around and then its the first table "bestelldatabase" which only returns one row.
So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `on` statement and `join` the two tables based on the related columns, in this case `bestelldatabase.id` and `zurückschreibendatas.bestellid`.

So the whole query comes out as:

```
SELECT bestelldatabase.*, zurückschreibendatas.* 
FROM bestelldatabase 
LEFT JOIN zurückschreibendatas 
on bestelldatabase.id = zurückschreibendatas.bestellid 
WHERE bestelldatabase.lieferscheinid = ?
```

the `where` limits the data returned and the `on` tells how the join should map.